# MS Word VBA: Saving a Word Doc as the First 2 Words on Every Page

Tags: vba, ms-word, data-extraction

I used a mail merge from excel to pull in 400 pages of labels into 1 word document. Each page has the same label 6 times in a 2x3 format with each page being unique. I currently have a VBA code to split up each page and save it with the correct margins needed. It then saves the document as the document name + what page number it is.

However, I would like the document name for each label as the first 2 words on the page it is on.

For example, if the label looks like the below, I would want the document to save as 'Chipole Burrito.docx'

**Chipotle Burrito**

- steak (double)
- white rice

Below is the code I used to save the document with the page number.

```VB
docSingle.Range.Find.Execute Findtext:="^m", ReplaceWith:=""

strNewFileName = Replace(docMultiple.FullName, ".doc", "_" & Right$("000" & iCurrentPage, 4) & ".doc")

docSingle.SaveAs strNewFileName
```

Comment: Having done the mailmerge label setup, change the mailmerge main document type to 'letters' and use the macro in the *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* topic in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** page at https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html to generate the individual pages directly from the mailmerge.

Answer (score -1):

This should get you the first words, basically accessing the Words object and returning the 1st and 2nd item:

```
Private Sub GetFirstTwoWords()
    With ActiveDocument
        Debug.Print Trim$(.Range(.Words(1).Start, .Words(2).End).Text)
    End With
End Sub
```

Or you can get the first paragraph text if it's possible to have label with more/less than 2 words:

```
Private Sub GetFirstParagraphText()
    With ActiveDocument
        Debug.Print Trim$(.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The OP clearly says he needs to extract «the First 2 Words on Every Page», not just for the document as a whole.

Comment: OP already has code that split up each page which is most likely to a new document (docSingle) so that he can save as a new document so this is still applicable as he can get the first 2 words on the new document itself.

Comment: @RaymondWu I called this function in my loop and it worked for each page! Thank you for your help on this!

Comment: @vikings1228  Glad to know it works for your case!